# Integration of $(5x^2+2x-5)/(x^3-x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem is to evaluate $\int \frac{5x^2+2x-5}{x^3-x}\,dx$.

[image: This is the problem.]

This is the solution that I tried:

[image: This is the solution that I tried.]

I really have no idea of this problem.

After check my solution, if there are any problem that I missed, or if approaching is wrong, please tell me how to approach this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A start:** Use *partial fractions*. Find constants $A,B,C$ such that your function is equal to $\displaystyle \frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x-1}+\frac{C}{x+1}$.

Comment: Thank you ! That was the short, but perfect answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\int\frac{5x^2+2x-5}{x^3-x}dx=\int\frac{5(x^2-1)+2x}{x(x^2-1)}dx=\int\frac{5(x^2-1)}{x(x^2-1)}dx+\int\frac{2}{x^2-1}dx=$$

$$=\int\frac{5}{x}dx+\int\frac{2}{x^2-1}dx=
5\int\frac{1}{x}dx+2\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}dx$$

The first is easy now, for the second you have to manipulate a little:

$$\int\frac{1}{x^2-1}dx=\int\frac{1}{(x+1)(x-1)}dx=\int(\frac{A}{x+1}+\frac{B}{x-1})dx$$

and find A and B.

Comment: thanks; now it should be better